# Making all the buttons have a click sound with minimum code as possible

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-button

I have a project with around 100-200 clickable views all of which have `OnClickListener`. I want to make them play a sound when `onClick()` method gets fired. I know how to play a sound with `MediaPlayer`, however, I don't want to write the `MediaPlayer.start()` in every single `onClick()` method.

Is it possible to have a single interface that extends from `OnClickListener` which will enable all the buttons to produce a sound when clicked?

After writing the question down, I realized that, no matter what, I will need to change the code in every class that has a clickable view. But still, for the sake of future buttons what would be the best way to implement this behavior?

So far I tried: I created an interface called `SoundyClickListener` which extends from `OnClickListener`. There I implemented the `onClick` method. But I couldn't get my head around on how to make a sound then the `onClick` method gets called.

Comment: maybe I do not fully understand the question. Why cannot you write a function in a class "Utils" for example and then call that function in each method? I suppose you have to write the logic for each button anyway, right? Or each of the 200 buttons have the same logic?

Comment: @AM13 touché. Yeah, that was a stupid question to ask. In whatever solution I get, I will need to update the whole shebang. Turns out, I needed someone to tell me this. Deleting the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button  = findViewById(R.id.button);    

 button.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
     {
                
            }
        });
```